# How do I deploy a grails application built on hudson to JbossAS 7?

Tags: grails, hudson, jboss7.x, hudson-plugins

We have a grails application that we build using hudson. Hudson used to deploy the generated war to tomcat through the tomcat-manager. Now that we are moving to JBoss 7, there is no obvious step available in hudson to deploy to JBoss7. Is there are plugin for JBoss7 deployment that I can use? Or commands to perform deployments on JBoss7?

Comment: I finally went with JBoss6 after wasting many hours in trying to deploy from hudson to Jboss7 using shell scripts/curl.

Answer (score 1):

You should check this out:
https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/

Also if you prefer to use scripting: https://github.com/maxandersen/as7scripting (it might be a little bit outdated now)

Regards